# Logitech USB keyboard not recognized on MSI laptop running Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, logitech-keyboard

When I plugged it in I noticed that there was no 'new hardware found' message. So I unplugged it and tried another port. I got the message this time around but Windows 7 (64-bit) failed to install the driver.

The keyboard shows up in Device Manager and its status is listed as 'driver not installed'.

I tried unstalling, then reinstalling. No success.

I tried updating the driver and setting random USB Keyboad and HID device drivers by hand. No success.

I tried unstalling and rebooting and then a really weird thing happend: the keyboard worked on the login screen and I used it to type in my password, but then Windows tried to install the driver again and killed it.

There is no USB keyboard setting in BIOS setup and the keyboard works fine both in BIOS setup and the boot menu.

I'm kinda out of ideas.

**Update**: I forgot to mention that Logitech does not supply drivers for this model, which is really just your run-of-the-mill USB keyboard, albeit a bit thinner than most. I also tried doing an EC reset (remove power & battery and wait 5 minutes).

**Update 2**: I booted up under Linux and the keyboard worked. The same goes for my other laptop running Windows

Comment: Do other USB keyboards work or have they worked in the past?

Comment: Yes. I used to use another Logitech keyboard, but it was wireless and that was ages ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was some kind of fault with the OS itself because what eventually solved it was Windows 7 Service Pack 1. Now it just works. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing the drivers from Logitech? From your question, I'm assuming you only tried through the Windows automatic installation.

Try installing the drivers directly from Logitech. They will have your exact model listed with the right drivers to download.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too. After finding the keyboard and selecting my OS, instead of getting a DL link, I was politely informed that W7 contains the necessary drivers.